# From kibana elastic search for a string with apostrophe with lucene query syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, apostrophe

I have entries like:

> message:
>       2017-10-18 19:32:28,243 | httpSSLWorkerThread-28080-53 | 754883 | XYZ | server1 | INFO | ElpasedTime - **(0' 1'' 2ms)** | select * from
>   countries @timestamp:
>       October 18th 2017, 19:32:49.000 tag:sometag.somefile.log
>   _id:
>       AV8wi3hgkonXqExERTgE
>   _type:
>       fluentd
>   _index:
>       logstash-2017.10.18

The time after "ElpasedTime" means the elapsed time for the query. I want to search for queries lasting more then 1 second, how should I do that???

At least to obtain queries with 1 second I have tried:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "1'' *ms"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

but with no luck. The double apostrophe of the seconds is the problem, in elasticsearch I can't search for this character, I've tried escaping in any way, even using "\u0027"...